# No Internet, no network adaptor, how do I install it?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, internet

Something was wrong with my pc yada yada yada,
I reinstalled windows 7 with a disk and used the custom version and now lost all my drivers and don't know how to reinstall them.
I have no Internet, my computers not even showing the router that is plugged into.
It's not showing anything I plug into my computer such as my phone or USB sticks
I have no idea how to sort it out..., What steps should i take?

Comment: My best guess is it was the 'yada yada yada' that broke it. Either that or the 'custom version'. Figure out precisely what that was & there's your answer.

Comment: I dont know what I did, I just pressed custom and didn't really change anything from that just next next next, I don't know anything about computers at all, my computer either had a virus on it or something and was told it needed reinstalling so I did and I read through it and thought the custom thing sounded more efficient, clearly I was wrong.

Comment: You need goto another computer, and download the network drivers, and burn them to DVD and install them.  Now your networking is up, goto http://devid.info    Download the tool on the top, http://devid.info/v2/DevID_agent_installer.exe    During install, uncheck the box so it doesn't install Total Commander.  Run, seach for drivers, when done click install and wait.  Reboot, and most devices should be working.

Answer (score 1):

What's your question here exactly?  How to install a network driver without internet?

Well, you're going to need a computer with network access to download the correct driver.  You are also going to need to burn it to a disk but I don't know if you have a cd/dvd drive (I assume you do as you say you installed from a disk) and since your usb ports aren't working a usb stick is out of the question.

Your best bet is to reinstall Windows from a verified clean ISO (ie. from Microsoft) to avoid the yada yada yada and "custom version" crap that you installed.

Comment: A verified clean ISO?